# Nokogiri Throwing Exception in Function but not outside of Function

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm new to Ruby and am using Nokogiri to parse html webpages. An error is thrown in a function when it gets to the line:

`currentPage = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))`

I have verified the inputs of the function, url is a string with a webaddress. The line I previously mention works exactly as intended when used outside of the function, but not inside. When it gets to that line inside the function the following error is thrown:

```
WebCrawler.rb:25:in `explore': undefined method `+@' for #<Nokogiri::HTML::Document:0x007f97ea0cdf30> (NoMethodError)
from WebCrawler.rb:43:in `<main>'
```

The function the problematic line is in is pasted below.

```
def explore(url)
    if CRAWLED_PAGES_COUNTER > CRAWLED_PAGES_LIMIT
            return
    end
    CRAWLED_PAGES_COUNTER++

    currentPage = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
    links = currentPage.xpath('//@href').map(&:value)

    eval_page(currentPage)

    links.each do|link|
            puts link
            explore(link)
    end
end
```

Here is the full program (It's not much longer):

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

#Crawler Params
START_URL = "https://en.wikipedia.org"
CRAWLED_PAGES_COUNTER = 0
CRAWLED_PAGES_LIMIT = 5

#Crawler Functions
def explore(url)
    if CRAWLED_PAGES_COUNTER > CRAWLED_PAGES_LIMIT
            return
    end
    CRAWLED_PAGES_COUNTER++

    currentPage = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
    links = currentPage.xpath('//@href').map(&:value)

    eval_page(currentPage)

    links.each do|link|
            puts link
            explore(link)
    end
end

def eval_page(page)
    puts page.title
end

#Start Crawling


explore(START_URL)
```

Comment: First, don't crawl Wikipedia, just don't. Use their API instead. When writing a crawler, learn to use the robots.txt file and honor it. Also, throttle your code to be a good network citizen or be prepared to have your code banned.

Comment: Ruby doesn't support post-increment or decrement (`CRAWLED_PAGES_COUNTER++`). You have to use `+= 1`. Also, you're using constants (`CRAWLED_PAGES_COUNTER`) instead of a variable. Perhaps that's because you don't understand variable scoping, but don't do that either. Variables are named using snake_case, not camelCase so `currentPage` should be `current_page`.

Comment: Didn't know Ruby was case sensitive when it came to variable names. Do you have any resources on robots.txt and throttling code? I'm not doing anything crazy with this code so I didn't think I'd be bothering anyone with it.

Comment: There are all sorts of resources for those on SO and the internet. Scraping Wikipedia has little value in comparison to using their API, which is very rich. Also, consider this, they're a free, non-commercial, site, so hitting them raises their operating costs. Find some site that makes a bunch of money from it and practice on them. An alternative is to run `gem server` on your local machine and scrape it. :-)

Comment: I was scraping wikipedia because I figured it would have a large number of links to look over and test my crawler on, but you're right I shouldn't be scraping a non profit site. Somebody told me about https://example.com in one of the comments below  so I'll be using it in the future. Still got a lot to learn, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

#Crawler Params
$START_URL = "https://en.wikipedia.org"
$CRAWLED_PAGES_COUNTER = 0
$CRAWLED_PAGES_LIMIT = 5

#Crawler Functions
def explore(url)
    if $CRAWLED_PAGES_COUNTER > $CRAWLED_PAGES_LIMIT
            return
    end
    $CRAWLED_PAGES_COUNTER+=1

    currentPage = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
    links = currentPage.xpath('//@href').map(&:value)

    eval_page(currentPage)

    links.each do|link|
            puts link
            explore(link)
    end
end

def eval_page(page)
    puts page.title
end

#Start Crawling


explore($START_URL)
```

Comment: I did this and it worked, now I'm getting new errors. So partial success? lol thanks for the help :)

Comment: Using `$` globals is not the right fix for the problem. Instead, recommend idiomatic (Ruby standard programming) practices.

Comment: @JHam, because the link you get for example "/w/load.php?debug=false&lang=en&modules=site.styles&only=styles&skin=vector" is not a complete url, please check why the link you get is not complete, or you maybe need to add the domain name in front of the link to make it be a complete url for 'open-uri' gem

Comment: Realized this with the help of another answer that was deleted and added a check for url completeness. Now I'm getting redirect loop errors lol baby steps.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you something to build from, this is a simple spider that only harvests and visits links. Modifying it to do other things would be easy.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'set'

BASE_URL = 'http://example.com'
URL_FORMAT = '%s://%s:%s'
SLEEP_TIME = 30 # in seconds

urls = [BASE_URL]
last_host = BASE_URL
visited_urls = Set.new
visited_hosts = Set.new

until urls.empty?
  this_uri = URI.join(last_host, urls.shift)
  next if visited_urls.include?(this_uri)

  puts "Scanning: #{this_uri}"

  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(this_uri.open)
  visited_urls << this_uri

  if visited_hosts.include?(this_uri.host)
    puts "Sleeping #{SLEEP_TIME} seconds to reduce server load..."
    sleep SLEEP_TIME
  end

  visited_hosts << this_uri.host

  urls += doc.search('[href]').map { |node|
    node['href'] 
  }.select { |url|
    extension = File.extname(URI.parse(url).path)
    extension[/\.html?$/] || extension.empty?
  }

  last_host = URL_FORMAT % [:scheme, :host, :port].map{ |s| this_uri.send(s) }
  puts "#{urls.size} URLs remain."
end
```

It:

- Works on http://example.com. That site is designed and designated for experimenting.
- Checks to see if a page was visited previously and won't scan it again. It's a naive check and will be fooled by URLs containing queries or queries that are not in a consistent order.
- Checks to see if a site was previously visited and automatically throttles the page retrieval if so. It could be fooled by aliases.
- Checks to see if a page ends with ".htm", ".html" or has no extension. Anything else is ignored.

The actual code to write an industrial strength spider is much more involved. Robots.txt files need to be honored, figuring out how to deal with pages that redirect to other pages either via HTTP timeouts or JavaScript redirects is a fun task, dealing with malformed pages are a challenge....

Comment: This is a fantastic response, will definitely be using http://example.com in the future. The code is a fantastic resource, I'll be referencing it a lot in the future. Thanks! :D

Comment: Well, it's a very quick and dirty example. Code to do it "for reals" is much more complex, and should involve a database to store which links were visited and which need to be checked. In a previous life I wrote a lot of them as part of my job duties, and there's a lot to think about and code. In this example, Set is substituting for a database but it definitely isn't persistent.